# Using nested special callable types throws TypeError: ... object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following Class

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self):
        from collections import defaultdict
        self.eggs = defaultdict(list)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        class AdderHelper:
            def __init__(self, eggs):
                self.eggs = eggs
            def __iadd__(self, egg):
                self.eggs.append(egg)
                return self
        return AdderHelper(self.eggs[index])
```

To provide an indexed in-place add operator, I defined a Helper class (similar to iterator pattern) and provided the next level operator to be called on the instance of the class.

For example, I intended to provide the following operator behaviour

```
spam = Spam()
spam[0] += 1
```

Unfortunately, Python did not like it and complained

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-82-ee0bba1041e3>", line 1, in <module>
    spam[0] = 1

TypeError: 'Spam' object does not support item assignment
```

Interestingly, if I assign the result of **getitem**, it just works

```
obj = spam[0]
obj += 1
```

Looks like, I simply do not understand the behaviour
Nevertheless, for in-place add, it does invokes the **setitem** and the only way to get over it is to override the **setitem** function as in

```
 def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    obj = self.__getitem__(index)
    obj += value
    return self
```

**Note**

Q1: @vaultah spam[0] += 1 is basically spam[0] = spam[0] + 1

I couldn't;t find any documentation to support that python would treat an in-place operator as a binary-op with the first operand as self. Even the disassembly says otherwise

```
def foo(spam):
    spam[0] += 1
dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (spam)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              4 DUP_TOP_TWO
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             10 INPLACE_ADD
             12 ROT_THREE
             14 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: `spam[0] = 1` calls `__setitem__`, not `__getitem__`.

Comment: @vaultah: Sorry there was a typographical error

Comment: My point still stands. `spam[0] += 1` is basically `spam[0] = spam[0] + 1`

Comment: @vaultah. I couldn't;t find any reference where it says python would treat an in-place operator as a binary-op with first operand as self. Even the disassembly says otherwise

Comment: Yes, sorry, I skipped over the `__iadd__` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is an augmented assignment operator that calls the `__iadd__` method of the LHS, if it exists, and *then assigns its return value to the LHS*:

> For instance, if x is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()`
>   method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`.

([source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__))

Thus

```
spam = Spam()
spam[0] += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
spam = Spam()
spam[0] = spam[0].__iadd__(1)
```

While `spam[0]` succeeds because `__getitem__` is implemented, subsequent assignment to `spam[0]` does not, since it needs `__setitem__` to work. At the same time, the `spam[0].eggs` list is updated, since `__iadd__` works as expected:

```
In [4]: spam[0].eggs
Out[4]: [1]
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error) for a related FAQ.